# Move zip file with today's date (like ABC_20161010_DEF.zip) from Linux server to Windows server using sftp

Tags: sftp

I am using below code to move zip file.

Unfortunately I am unable to get set part right. I want to set Dt to have value like "ABC_20161010_DEF.zip"

```
open UserNameHere@ServerNameHere
ascii
cd "ValidPathHere"
lcd "ValidPathHere"

Set Dt=SomePrefixHere_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_SomeSuffixHere.zip
get Dt

pause
quit
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing SFTP client (OpenSSH `sftp`?) commands (`open`, `get`, etc.) with Windows batch file commands (`set`). That's not possible.

You have to call the `set` from Windows batch file and then use the resolved value in the SFTP script. How to do that depends on capabilities of your SFTP client.

If you are using the OpenSSH `sftp`, you have to generate the script on the fly, as its script cannot resolve environment variables. In the other hand, the OpenSSH `sftp` does not have the `ascii` command. So I'm not sure, what client you are using actually.

Also note that using the `date` environment variable is not reliable. It gives different values with different locale.  For example, on the US locale the `%date%` resolves to `ddd, mm/dd/yyyy`, so you will get `yyyymmdd`. On the contrary, on the UK locale, the `%date%` resolves to `dd/mm/yyyy`, so you will get `yyyyddmm`. On other locales, you can get yet another results.

---

An easy and more reliable solution, is using the [WinSCP SFTP client](https://winscp.net/), with its locale-independent [`%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp). WinSCP also supports the [ascii/text mode (using the `-transfer=ascii` switch)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get#transfer), if you need that.

With [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting), you can use a batch file (`.bat`) like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="C:\writable\path\to\log\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@example.com/ -hostkey=""...""" ^
    "get -transfer=ascii ""/remote/path/SomePrefixHere_%%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%%"" ""C:\local\path\""" ^
    "exit"
```

You can even have [WinSCP generate the script/batch file template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) for you.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*